# Firebase “Device was registered”

Tags: ios, firebase, ios-provisioning

When distributing our app via Firebase one of our devices only get a “device was registered” message instead of a download link.

The message continues to tell me that the device needs to be registered and with the next version I will be able to test the application. But that was 5 releases ago. The device has long been registered. I have even installed the application via Xcode.

This error message seem to be a false negative. What do I need to do to make Firebase take notice that the device has indeed been registered?

Comment: This doesn't really sound like a coding question - it's more server related and something you should reach out to [Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support) for. If it is a coding question, can you include the problematic code as we'll take a look.

Comment: @jay I can try but in my experience official support is rarely supportive. Nowadays all you get is some unhelpful canned answers by some bot.

Also Firebase support points right back here.

Comment: That has not been my experience. The Firebasers are VERY active here and support has been spot on for all the years I've been Firebasing (7?). The question is pretty vague as is because we don't know the implementation and that sounds like a server message which is not something we can directly help with. Give support a try and if that fails, loop us in with further details.